# New to Lua - Table operation

Tags: lua, lua-table

Can someone explain this to me?  I have figured it out through this [tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial) that this is known as a table. Coming from a **C**/C++ background, can someone explain how this works (I am trying to understand some existing Lua code)?

```
config = {
  devices = {
    C56    = "/dev/ttyS2",
    ELTRA  = "/dev/ttyS3",
--  MICORE = "/dev/ttyS4",
    HID    = "/dev/ttyS1",

    KEYCARD = {
  --  [6] = { tty="/dev/ttyS1", speed=9600 },
      [7] = { tty="/dev/ttyS4", speed=9600 },
    },

  },
}
```

Is it a config table, consisting of a device table but then there is a KEYCARD table? What are C56 and ELTRA called in Lua? Are they fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A table in Lua is just an untyped map, like Javascript objects or Python dictionaries.  The table associates one value (like "devices" or 6) with another value (like "/dev/ttyS2").  The value could be another table.  Tables are used to create objects, maps, and arrays.

In your example, the *config* variable references a table.  That table has one element, "devices", whose value is another table.  That table has 5 elements.  Four of those elements ("C56", "ELTRA", "MICORE", and "HID") have strings as their values.  The fifth element ("KEYCARD") has a table as its value.  *That* table has two elements (6, 7) whose values are other tables (each of two elements).

Answer (score 3):

You have a config table two subtables within it, devices and Keycard, which is a subtable of devices.  It's been a while since I used Lua, but to access, for example ELTRA, you'd type Config.devices.ELTRA and to access the 7 keycard you type Config.devices.KEYCARD[7]
To get at the speed of the keycard, you could do
speed = Config.devices.KEYCARD[7].speed

Comment: Also note that Keycard[6] and MICORE are commented out.

Comment: So in a sense, it is like a struct in C

Comment: I'm sure someone is going to jump on me for being not quite technically correct here, but yes. If you are comming from c++ or c, that's a good way to think about it. A struct with losely typed members that you can add to on the fly.

Comment: @Changeling: It's not like a struct in that 1) all its fields are not known when the object is first created, 2) it doesn't have a fixed layout in memory, 3) fields can be added and removed at any time, 4) its access is more like a hashtable lookup (I think) than a fixed memory offset, hence slower, 5) the syntax to access elements is different. How's it like a struct? Well, you store data in them and have a way of getting the data back out. :-)

Comment: @Owen: Thanks for the clarification :) I was trying to reason the meaning in my head and the only way at the time was to use the struct example albeit a poor one.